# quadratic diophantine expression

Tags: number-theory

Can someone suggest a reference?

Also, why are there 7 answers to the question

39*c^2 + 3*c + 1 mod 49 is congruent to 0

see my Maple worksheet.

[image: maple worksheet screenshot]

I sort of answered my own question.  If 49 divides b then so does 7.  Reducing mod 7 gives

$$4c^2 + 3c + 1 mod 7 = 0$$
Multiplying by 2 and adding 7 yields a perfect square.
$$(c+3)^2 mod 7 = 0$$
The 7 answers fall out from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the solution is $c =3 \pmod{7}$, you started the problem $\pmod{49}$. There are 7 residue classes modulo $49$ which can be $3 \pmod{7}$, and in this case all seven work.

To learn how to go from $\pmod{7}$ to $\pmod{49}$, or more generally from solving a polynomial equation $\pmod{p}$ to solving the same equation $\pmod{p^n}$ read on [Hensel's Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hensel%27s_lemma)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:  $39\equiv-10\mod 49$, so the quadratic can be rewritten as

$$10c^2-3c-1\equiv0\mod 49$$

Note that $10c^2-3c-1=(5c+1)(2c-1)$.